# Why am I getting this error: java.sql.SQLException: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am getting the following error while running a batch job.

```
sql.SQLException: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared
```

In what cases is this error encountered ?

Comment: I was not sure whether I even wanted to comment on this. If you don't even find the time to phrase a question, you maybe should try to get help somewhere else?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380813/how-to-get-rid-of-mysql-error-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. Take a look at this [thread](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/371993/1600705#post1600705).