# mysql prepared statement error in projects hosted on amazon

Tags: mysql, database-administration

All my applications on `amazon rws` are throwing back the error below.

I am using `zend framework` for my projects and error only comes after application is used for some time.

I tried to flush the cache stored and it worked fine.
 
So i think the issue is with some configuration in mysql which i need to do, so can anyone suggest what might be the exact problem and what i need to do ?

Error message:
`Mysqli statement execute error : Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared Notice: Undefined variable: country_list`

Comment: could you add examples of the code you are using? may help debug?

Comment: That first error message looks like it might be worth Googling

Comment: Indeed: see eg. [How to get rid of MySQL error 'Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4380813)