# How to join on a select result with eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to join on a result of other select like this :

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE1
  JOIN (
  SELECT cat_id FROM TABLE2 where brand_id = 2 GROUP BY TABLE2.cat_id) AS b ON TABLE1.id = b.cat_id
```

is there any way to do this with eloquent?

Comment: What's your data model like exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079281/laravel-fluent-query-builder-join-with-subquery), using `DB:raw()` will solve your problem.

```
DB::table('table1')->join(DB::raw("(SELECT 

          cat_id

          FROM table2

          WHERE brand_id = 2   

          GROUP BY table2.cat_id

          ) as b"),function($join){

            $join->on("b.cat_id","=","table1.id");

      })->get();
```

Comment: how can I add where  brand_id = 2 inside of this query?

Comment: brand_id is a column of which table? table1 or 2?

Comment: do you know how can I get result in colloction or array? for now I have answer like this : 0 => {#614 ▼
    +"id": 184

Comment: Well, you can add a toArray() like this to convert the result into an array.
   
`DB::table('table1')->.................->get()->toArray();`

Comment: no, I want to convert stdclass to collection, to Array only give me first level of result in array format, I want to get all result in Collection or array

Answer (score 1):

```
\DB::table('table1')->join('table2' , function($join){
   $join->on('table1.id', '=', 'table2.cat_id');
})->select(['table2.cat_id' , 'table1.*'])
->where('table2.brand_id' , '=' , '2')
->groupBy('table2.cat_id');
```

Depends on whether brand_id is in table1 or table2

You can also use model approach for it.

```
TABLE1::join('table2' , function($join){
   $join->on('table1.id', '=', 'table2.cat_id');
})->select(['table2.cat_id' , 'table1.*'])
->where('table2.brand_id' , '=' , '2')
->groupBy('table2.cat_id');
```

Comment: Actually that's not eloquent (what you call "Model approach"), but query builder.

Comment: you want to do it with relations ?

Comment: this is not with eloquent and not give me answer like query.

Comment: my answer is record of table1 but this give me only cat_id from table2 like this : array:2 [▼
  0 => {#615 ▼
    +"cat_id": 184
  }
  1 => {#614 ▼
    +"cat_id": 185
  }
]

Comment: do u want to do it with relations ? @HamidNaghipour

Comment: that's not important only give answer like down answer.

Comment: i have given the answer. just add the values you want from the other table in the select like 

select(['table2.cat_id' , 'table1.*']);