# How to SELECT from a view in SQL? (General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

UPDATE:
The query is working perfectly as follows; the error solely appears when I select from the view.

```
$query = "
SELECT ModuleID, ModuleName, Credits, Lecturer, Room, EmployeeID, Forename, Surname, RoomID, RoomCode
FROM ((Module 
INNER JOIN Employee ON Module.Lecturer = Employee.EmployeeID) 
INNER JOIN Room ON Module.Room = Room.RoomID)
";

$result = $DBH->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
$data = $result->fetchAll();
```

I'm receiving the following error when trying to `SELECT * FROM` a view I created. (Selecting from a table works perfectly).

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared'

I have no issues when using

```
SELECT * FROM Module
```

Here is my query:

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM module_info
";

$result = $DBH->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
$data = $result->fetchAll();
```

The view I created:

```
CREATE VIEW module_info 
AS
SELECT ModuleID, ModuleName, Credits, Lecturer, Room, EmployeeID, Forename, Surname, RoomID, RoomCode
FROM ((Module 
INNER JOIN Employee ON Module.Lecturer = Employee.EmployeeID) 
INNER JOIN Room ON Module.Room = Room.RoomID);
```

Comment: what DBMS are you using? you can run the select in view?

Comment: Using a MySQL db, using workbench to create SQL scripts @RadimBača

Comment: @RadimBača Running SELECT * FROM module_info; in workbench results in the correct output with no errors

Comment: The following link is old, but have you looked into increasing the `table_definitition_cache`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380813/how-to-get-rid-of-mysql-error-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared

Comment: What's up with the brackets????  Way too many brackets.

Comment: @Eric I don't think there's any issue with brackets here

Comment: @Xander I don't say there's an issue with it, just not necessary.

Comment: @Eric Ah, the brackets in the query are unnecessary?

Comment: @Xander No it's not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in this instance was as follows:

## Emulation of prepared statements needs to be enabled.

In the connection file, the following line

```
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
```

needs to be changed like so:

```
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => true,
```

In other instances it appears the solution may be to increase the `table_definitition_cache`