# Database Responding Oddly to Queries via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've currently been pulling my hair out on this problem for about a full day now. I am developing my first application. I'm actually pretty far into it (having established the login page several weeks ago, worked perfectly). Last night, I ran my app and it worked perfectly. I backed it up to my flash drive, tested it once more, and closed my laptop down for the night.

This morning I opened up the app to begin the documentation process on it -- this is a project for my capstone so I have to document/video the outcome each week -- and suddenly my tester account couldn't be authenticated. I tried registering a new one via the app, and it doesn't post the data to the database. Naturally, I assumed the database/server was having issues and contacted my host; in a two-hour long process, they verified that the database was working and it was simply in my code which hadn't been touched since the night before when it ran perfectly.

I've read that this sometimes happens with authentication through FireBase (i believe this is what it is called) and OAuth. I'm using neither and just doing the basic database reading/writing. I've not found any useful information on what to do through Google, probably due to the fact that the problem is just too complicated for a quick search... or I just don't know how to word it correctly.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "SENSORED", "SENSORED", "SENSORED");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


$statement = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);


mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $name, $username, $email, $company_id, $phone, $password, $leaveTime, $sickTime, $rateOfPay);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["user_id"] = $user_id;
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["email"] = $email;
    $response["company_id"] = $company_id;
    $response["phone"] = $phone;
    $response["password"] = $password;
    $response["leaveTime"] = $leaveTime;
    $response["sickTime"] = $sickTime;
    $response["rateOfPay"] = $rateOfPay;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I did set up a connection test, which verified that the PHP is indeed connecting to the database and querying it. It can tell how many tables I have and, for example, how many usernames I have in the user table. However, when I enter:

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = 'test'"
```

being that there is a username that is just 'test', it cannot find a match. However, I can see from looking at the database that test is indeed a username and does exist in that table.

I currently am getting no results via PHP. However, if I query via PHPmyadmin, it displays the row that contains 'test' as a username. Obviously, my coding is correct, but I'm not sure what could be interfering with selecting it from the PHP since it is establishing a connection and reading from the database. Not to mention the fact that it isn't wanting to write the registration information to the database when there are no holds on that.

I've gone as far in looking for a solution as creating a whole new database with different credentials and such and receive the same problem. Google has been no help in the search for an answer, and I haven't managed to find a similar question/problem on here.

Any idea how a working database connection and reading/writing abilities can completely disappear without being edited overnight?

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` and `SELECT * ` is just asking for problems.  What happens when you add/remove a field from your table?

Comment: Can you explain why? I was taught that was the best way to go about this. I haven't tried it so I'm not sure. Adding a field via PHPmyadmin gave me no problems.

Comment: because the `*` is select all fields, and `bind_result` has a set number of inputs in a set order.  So if you add a field you in turn have to change the bind.  Consider if you add a field between `id` and `name`, you should define the fields in the SQL, to bake them and their order into the query, at the least.  Otherwise you could pull out $password as the phone number and display it by mistake if you re-ordered the DB table the wrong way

Comment: Well, yes, I'm selecting all fields because the user table has information I need to pass to the dashboard from the login screen, but that doesn't really matter. I've not minded needing to change the bind. Didn't seem like a huge deal to me, but it is nice to know that there is a more efficient way of accomplishing this. I'll be sure to update that when I get it actually up and running again.

Comment: Well thankfully your using prepared statements. But I would check the password with `hash_equals` and not look in the DB for it...

Comment: I'd rewrite it for you but I don't use MySqli any more, switched to PDO like 5 years ago...

Comment: Totally understandable. College likes to teach depreciated techniques; I'm just glad to know there is a better way and why this is not a good way to do it.

Comment: Does your PHP code reach the end of the script, i.e.: does it correctly `echo` the JSON with `success` being `false`? If not, you need to debug where the script fails: set up error reporting / displaying of errors, if you have not already, put `var_dump()` or other output statements at critical places to view where the script fails, etc. Also, try to limit the resultset by adding `LIMIT 1` to your SQL query and then only fetch a single row (i.e. don't use a `while` loop). See what `var_dump(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement));` outputs, for instance.

Comment: It does echo false, yes. I have debugged the script, and as stated in the question it cannot find the arguments given to it. For example, I hardcoded a username and password for it to check, and it cannot find it, but it will echo the given arguments back to me and finish the script. It just seems to be unable to find the username column, despite the fact they are the exact same word. If screenshots will be more helpful and a link to the working code I can provide those.

Comment: Okay, temporarily put `var_dump(mysqli_error($connection));` after each interaction with your connection to see if that tells you something noteworthy (especially if `var_dump(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement));` returns `false` or `null`). You may want to do this in the script that is responsible for inserting data as well.

Comment: http://malloree-eady.design/Login.php   updated the code with what you said. Getting a lot of "Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared". According to almighty Google, this is some sort of bug with MySQL but I'm not seeing a lot of fixes on it so far.

Comment: Okay, at least we've discovered the likely culprit then. :) But I'm afraid I can't help you any further with this. However, on skimming [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380813/how-to-get-rid-of-mysql-error-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared), it appears to offer a (hacky?) solution. But otherwise perhaps you should ask a new question on StackOverflow that revolves around that error message. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

this is how I would do it.  As I said i haven't used MySqli in a number of years so I had to do some googling, and I am not 100% sure everything is correct as I can't really test it.

But here goes.

```
 //turn on output buffering - useful for debugging
 ob_start();
//I would use the object interface
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "SENSORED", "SENSORED", "SENSORED");

//your not checking the connection success
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$username = $_POST["username"];

//are you storing passwords in plain text?
$password = password_hash($_POST["password"]);


/*
 I would not pick the password from the DB, the DB is case insensitive,
 unless you use collation UTF8_bin or such.
 Also it's harder to debug, as you don't know if the user exists or the 
 password matching is wrong.
*/
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($connection, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");

//bind the inputs
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

//execute the query
$res = $stmt->execute();

  //fetch results as an associative array
$row = $res->fetch_assoc(); 

//set default
$response["success"] = false; 

/*
 We expect exactly 1 row be returned. More then 1 should
 be impossible if your username is unique (which is should be)
  but just in case any issues happen we should check that it's exactly
  1 return row, no more no less.
*/
if($res->num_rows() != 1) {
    //always be cordial in your error messages to users
    $response['message'] = "We're sorry we could not find user {$username}"; 
    return $response;
}

//check the password hash using an approved crypto-logically safe method
if(!hash_equals($password, $$row['password']) {   
    $response['message'] = "Unfortunately the password you entered is incorrect";
    return $response;
}

//remove the password / we no longer need it.
//security is paramount, no need to risk exposing it, even when its hashed
//eg. I just spent the weekend fixing 5 wordpress sites that were hacked
unset($row['password']); 


$response['message'] = "Success!";
//put the contents of the buffer into debug. only do this on localhost
//you could switch this using the HOST or server IP
$response['debug'] = ob_get_clean();

//combine the row with the response
//caution if key matched in rows exists in response value in row 
//will be replaced with that of response ( it shouldn't be a problem in this case )
$response += $row;

//set the correct content type, this allows browsers to 
//know this is json, and prevents having to do JSON.parse() in some cases
header('Content-type:application/json');

//encode the responce
echo json_encode($response);
```

I put some notes in there such as this

```
//always be cordial in your error messages to users
```

There was once a young web developer who had a client that complained his error messages were to "cold".  But this young web developer took his clients criticism to heart and remembered to always be extra nice to end users. ( that was around 2009).  That said, it hasn't improved my spelling.

One thing I ran across while refactoring this, is I noticed you are not encrypting the password.  I don't know if this is by mistake or by design.

`ob_start` and `ob_get_clean` allow you to `echo` or `print_r` stuff between them without breaking the `JSON` response.  Normally if you create output then it will be outside of your json data

```
 here is some output
 {"success" : false}
```

Which will cause errors on the client side. With output buffering the above will look like this

```
{"debug" : "here is some output", "success" : false}
```

I suppose it's optional, but it's the right way to do JSON or even any content type other than HTML, including (or especially) file downloads.

Hope it helps.  Even if you cant use the code in this form, it may help seeing it written a different way.  Sometimes you can be to close to the problem and overlook some simple mistake.  Looking at it in another format and having to process the logic of it, may shed light on something you missed.