# Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string on execute

Tags: php, mysqli

**Error:**

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be
>   converted to string in common.php on line 33

I know there are many topic out there with this title, but I read all, and none of those similar to my code, on line 33:

```
if (!$sql->execute()) {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $sql->error; // --> this is line 33
}
```

This part belong to this codes:

```
class User {
    public function getId(){

    global $connection;
    $id = $_COOKIE['userid'];
    $userid = $_COOKIE['auth'];

    $sql = $connection->prepare("SELECT tel, hash FROM seller WHERE id = ?");
    $sql->bind_param("s", $id);
    if (!$sql->execute()) {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $sql->error;
    }
    $sql->bind_result($tel, $hash);
    $sql->fetch();
    $sql->close();

    if(md5($hash) == $userid){
        $result = $tel;
    } else {
        $result = 0;
    }
    return $result;
    }
}
```

This morning I faced with this error suddenly and that code worked before. without no change I got this error. any idea?

The interesting part of this kind of error is, when I comment that line, I will get another similar error for another `mysqli` execute. why this happened?

I know what this error mean, but It just for until today, I didn't change anything and it just echo error of execute. so why?

Comment: `echo "Error: " . $sql...` <- right there, you are trying to concatenate `$sql` (which is a `mysqli_stmt` object) into a **string**. This cannot be done, so don't do it

Comment: You can get better error reporting from MySQLi and avoid checking the return values of its methods if you set `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)` before creating the DB connection. This will cause it to throw exceptions on errors

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, you are trying to express a `mysqli_stmt` object (`$sql`) as a string, which is not possible. You probably wanted to do this:

```
$query = "SELECT tel, hash FROM seller WHERE id = ?";
$sql = $connection->prepare($query);
$sql->bind_param("s", $id);
if (!$sql->execute()) {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $sql->error;
}
```

Comment: Error: `Error: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error. Answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380813/how-to-get-rid-of-mysql-error-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared) might help.