# 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I was using prepare statement inside mysql stored procedure in codeIgniter  3.1.7framework. Everything works fine when I was working in localhost But when the website was hosted, I got this error "Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared" I checked for solution in too many websites and checked codeigniter , mysql documentation. But still I can't solve it. Almost everyone mentioned to increase "table_definition_cache" in sql. But I tried and still I was getting the same error. Expecting some solution from experts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't get solution but Someone has down voted my question, Let me know why.

Comment: does CI 3.1.7 use PDO? if yes, you can try to emulate prepared statements `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true`

Comment: I Feel like **yes**... Let me check

Comment: @DenisAlimov I changed my database connection from mysqli to pdo.. But still the same result.

Everything works good when doing in local host,, After hosted I am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

I was working with Laravel Framework and stuck with the same issue. I googled and tried many solutions but didn't the rid of this issue. 
Finally, I got this solution and got rid of this issue.

Solution: [MySQL: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared](http://blog.corrlabs.com/2013/04/mysql-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re.html)

You can also see these solutions:

[Solution1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380813/how-to-get-rid-of-mysql-error-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared)

[Solution2:](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144427/getting-error-err-1615-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared-with-mys)

I hope this will also work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the value of the variable **table_definition_cache**

It could be increased in line with the sentence **SET GLOBAL table_definition_cache=value;**

Modify in **my.conf** file