# Making a union of views in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, union, sql-view

I'm creating a MySQL stored procedure that receives the names of two views, and performs a Union upon them into the first of the two.

I've used prepared statements to take view names as strings, so I can use this stored procedure with a wealth of other stored procedures that produce views of varying names.

The following code works as expected:

```
DROP view if exists test1;
DROP view if exists test2;

CREATE VIEW test1 as SELECT "Cows";
CREATE VIEW test2 as SELECT "Horses";

DROP VIEW if exists tempView;
CREATE VIEW tempView AS SELECT * FROM test1 UNION SELECT * FROM test2;
SELECT * from tempView;
```

However, when I execute the following code:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_unionViews //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_unionViews(IN viewname varchar(255), 
                               IN viewname2 varchar(255))
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS tempView;
    SET @in1 = viewname;
    SET @in2 = viewname2;
    SET @str = 'CREATE VIEW tempView AS 
       SELECT * FROM ? UNION SELECT * FROM ?';
    PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @in1, @in2;

    SET @str2 = 'DROP VIEW ?';
    SET @in3 = viewname;
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @str2;
    EXECUTE stmt2 USING @in3;

    SET @str3 = 'CREATE VIEW ? AS SELECT * FROM tempView';
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @str3;
    EXECUTE stmt3 USING @in3;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END //
DELIMITER ;

DROP view if exists test1;
DROP view if exists test2;

CREATE VIEW test1 as SELECT "Cows";
CREATE VIEW test2 as SELECT "Horses";
CALL SP_unionViews(test1, test2);
SELECT * from test1;
```

I get the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'test1' in 'field list'
```

That would seem to indicate that this stored procedure is trying to use test1 as a column somewhere it's not intended to be one. But I can't figure out where.

UPDATE:
When edited as below, I expected the solution to work, but it gives me another error.

The new code reads:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_unionViews //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_unionViews(IN viewname varchar(255), 
                               IN viewname2 varchar(255))
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS tempView;
    SET @str = CONCAT('
    CREATE VIEW tempView AS 
        SELECT * FROM ', viewname, ' UNION SELECT * FROM ', viewname2);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SET @str2 = CONCAT('DROP VIEW ', viewname, ';');
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @str2;
    EXECUTE stmt2;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

    SET @str3 = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW ', viewname ,' AS SELECT * FROM tempView');
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @str3;
    EXECUTE stmt3;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END //
DELIMITER ;

DROP view if exists test1;
DROP view if exists test2;

CREATE VIEW test1 as SELECT "Cows";
CREATE VIEW test2 as SELECT "Horses";
CALL SP_unionViews("test1", "test2");
SELECT * from test1;
```

And its error reads:

```
#1615 - Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared
```

Comment: btw, please don't worry about the 'Select *' stuff. This is boilerplate.

Comment: Edited to fix:
"test1", "test2" needed to be string literals.

Comment: Also edited to fix: Creating a view didn't like the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use parameters for table names in a prepared statement, so you will need to put the table names into the query string before you prepare the statement. Try changing your queries to these:

```
SET @str = CONCAT('
CREATE VIEW tempView AS 
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM ', viewname, ' UNION SELECT * FROM ', viewname2, '
    )');

SET @str2 = CONCAT('DROP VIEW ', viewname);

SET @str3 = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW ', viewname, ' AS SELECT * FROM tempView');
```

Once you have done this you will no longer need any parameters to the `EXECUTE`s

Comment: Are parameters in prepared statements only useful for columns and comparison values, then?

Comment: Oh, I see. This is a question of what the '?' can do.

Comment: @Feygon they can basically only be used for data literals.

Comment: @Feygon sorry about the missing `)`s, I've edited the answer.

Comment: New Error.
I really thought your solution would work.

Comment: It should... Here are some links which might solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380813/how-to-get-rid-of-mysql-error-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144427/getting-error-err-1615-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared-with-mys http://blog.corrlabs.com/2013/04/mysql-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re.html

Comment: Oh, bummer. It looks like it's an issue with my super user status. I can't increase the cache size for creating tables, which is required for dynamic view creation using prepared statements.
I guess I'll try something else. I want to keep using this platform.