# (Too) many views causing problems

Tags: php, mysql, view, mariadb

I have a little large database application using PHP and MariaDB 10.3.

I have about 100 tables, and then about 3,000 views.

When exceeding something like 1,000 views, the database schema breaks down and stops being accessible. The tables are stil fine, but all the views break down. When query any of the views it gives different error messages like "prepared statements need to be re-prepared" or "lost connection".

The primary problem is not about table cache as extending this does not solve the problem. It is not either about how to emulate the prepared statements. I have tried those strategies already.

Someone knows this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of MySQL error 'Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380813/how-to-get-rid-of-mysql-error-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared)

Comment: This does not solve this problem - even one of the error messages is same.

Comment: the duplicate suggest that the cause might be anything from: 1) bug, 2) configuration, 3) an actual need to re-prepare the query, 4) hosting. we cant exactly help the problem as its pretty wide..

Comment: While I can't speak for MariaDB specifically, I would observe that views in MySQL offer remarkably limited benefit, given their inability to utilise underlying indexes. Also, 100 tables is quite a lot - possibly large enough to be indicative of poor design.

Comment: 100 tables is not a lot for a large comprehensive application. Professional systems will easily have thousands. InnoDB has a limit of 4 billion tables. But again, the problem is not the tables but the views. And views in MariaDB are able to utilise the underlying indexes if you do not "force" MariaDB to create a temporary table. This is actually the reason for the large number of views as views on views will easily create this situation.

Comment: Which version?  I think there is a setting for number of prepared statements to cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `max_prepared_stmt_count`  It defaults to about 16K, so I don't think it is the problem.

Do you do `DEALLOCATE PREPARED STATEMENT` when finished with a statement?

Do the `VIEWs` call Stored Routines?

Do you have the Query cache turned on?

What is the value of table_open_cache?

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Subquery_cache%';`

Comment: Many good suggestions :-) Increasing table open cache is what I did and what solved it :-)