# how to use group_concat in native query spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

```
@Query(value = "select order_id, group_concat(code) from pnt_contracts where order_id = 11186 group by order_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object[]> test();
```

I get the error:

```
2023-06-20T13:54:17.971+07:00  WARN 62758 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1615, SQLState: HY000 
2023-06-20T13:54:17.972+07:00 ERROR 62758 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared
```

how I can fix it?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380813/how-to-get-rid-of-mysql-error-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared) helps